# how to properly create a between clause on mongo mapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongomapper

I'm trying to create a query like this

```
 User.find_each(created_at: [1.day.ago.utc, Date.now]) do |user|
```

but that didn't worked. Always return 0 users, but I do have users created in the 1 day timeframe. I believe I'm doing this query wrong, but the mongo mapper documentation says nothing about this. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- Activate the profiling with `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`.
- Rerun your code.
- Get the query you sent to MongoDB in the `system.profile` collection.
- Run this query in the mongoshell to check what's wrong.
- Update your code to send the command you want.